# Is there a way to edit wp export code file to export only draft values

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to customize the code inside wp export functionality to only export custom post type events from the draft, I do not want to use any plugin. I want to use wordpress default export functionality to export only draft values

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to go to **Export** page first? This is a built-in function of WordPress.

[image]